# regex to substitute leading 4 or 3 zeros under certain circumstances

Tags: regex

I'm trying to substitute a string if it has 4 leading zeros followed by an underscore `0000_` or if it has 3 leading zeros followed by a letter except `d`, `r`,`v`. Other strings shouldn't be touched:

```
0000_0001r => 1r
000a => a
```

My attempt is `(^0{3}[^\ddrv])?(^0{4}_)?` and it does match but how can I remove the leading zeros?

Regex Fiddle:
https://regex101.com/r/vf11lt/2

Comment: I am not sure about the `000d` test case (you have `d` as expected output, but the rule says it should not be modified), try [`^(?:0{3}(?=(?![drv])[a-z])|0{4}_)`](https://regex101.com/r/vf11lt/3)

Comment: excellent, can you provide this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:0{3}(?=(?![drv])[a-z])|0{4}_)
```

Use the case insensitive modifier if you need case insensitive behavior.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vf11lt/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?:` - start of an alternation group:

  - `0{3}` - 3 zeros
  - `(?=(?![drv])[a-z])` - a letter (`[a-z]`) that is not `d`, `r` or `v` (achieved with `(?![drv])` negative lookahead)
  - `|` - or
  - `0{4}_` - four zeros and a `_`
- `)` - end of the grouping.

In Java, you could write `(?![drv])[a-z]` as `[a-z&&[^drv]]`.
In .NET, you could write `(?![drv])[a-z]` as `[a-z-[drv]]`. This is called *character class subtraction*. The lookahead restriction will work in the majority of cases though.